# android capture youtube movie on webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube, capture

There are `ImageView` and `screenCapture` Button and `WebView` on Activity.

Load "http://youtube.com" on WebView.

You can see youtube page and click movie.

Movie will play in html.

Click Button to screen capture.

```
    View root = webView.getRootView();
    root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getDrawingCache());
    root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Set captured image to ImageView.

But there is no movie on captrued image. Just black area on.

Why can't capture movie?

How can I capture movie on WebView?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into a similar problem. There was my scene. I used `WebView` to load a web page. In the web page which was writted in `HTML5`, there was a `video` to play videos. I wanted to capture the `video`'s part content. So then, there are my codes:

**Initialize the `WebView`**:

```
String url = ...; 
VideoView vv;
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

**Override `WebChromeClient`**:

```
@Override
public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
    super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
    if (view instanceof FrameLayout){
        FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
        if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView){
            vv = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
        }
     }
}
```

**Then, there is `Capture()` method:**

```
public Bitmap capture(VideoView vv){
     MediaMetadataRetriever rev = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
     rev.setDataSource(mContext, Uri);//Uri is the Content URI of the data you want to play, well, call this method before the rest of the methods in this class. This method may be time-consuming.; 
     Bitmap bitmap = rev.getFrameAtTime(vv.getCurrentPosition() * 1000,
            MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
    return bitmap;
}
```

I don't know whether my solution can solve you question, but I hope you are inspired by my codes. Good luck.

Comment: @SilentKnight I'm having a similar problem and your answer looks very promising. I have one question though: what do you pass as `uri`? `Uri.parse(webView.getUrl())`?

Comment: `Uri` means "the Content URI of the data you want to play".